# Cannot add foreign key constraint to multi column pk

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I just have a simple question (I believe) regarding MySQL workbench and a script. The database I'm trying to create is really small; however, I am having problems when defining a foreign key. I get error 1215: cannot add foreign key constraint for the "Cuenta" table and I don't know why.

The database is called cajero and it has two tables: Cliente and Cuenta.

This is the script

```
USE cajero;
CREATE TABLE Cliente(
    usuario VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    passw VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    cuenta INT(10) NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    primary key(usuario)
)Engine=InnoDB;

alter table Cliente
    drop primary key,
    Add primary key(usuario, cuenta);

Use cajero;
CREATE TABLE Cuenta(
    idcuenta INT(10) NOT NULL,
    saldo float(15,2) NOT NULL,
    primary key(idcuenta)
)Engine=InnoDB;

Use cajero;
Alter table cuenta
    add foreign key(idcuenta) references Cliente(cuenta);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your FK in your `Cuenta` table references only one column of your multi-column PK in your `Cliente` table. You either must create another index in `Cliente` only mentioning the `cuenta` column, or you must change the FK so it references all the columns in the PK.